# What happens when there is a current source at the drain and gate is GNDed?

Tags: mosfet, analog, current-source, nmos

In the circuit below, Vin = 0V and there is a 10 uA current source connected to 5V and the drain of the NMOS. Say there is a large resistance R1 at the source and the transistor's W/L is large and Vth = 1V,
[image]

1. What is the source voltage?
2. How will the transistor turn on? Vgs will always be negative if current is flowing down into R1 to GND.  If the transistor doesn't turn on, where does the current of 10 uA from the current source sink into?
3. To help sink the current, can the polarities at source or drain be such that the transistor is absorbing power instead of dissipating?

Comment: This reminds me of a homework question focused on validating underlying assumptions, and the wording also suggests that this might be a homework question. Our homework policy is not to give answers without a substantial attempt shown, but a few things to think about as hints toward your first attempt: 1) Is this an integrated, symmetric FET, or a discrete one? If it's symmetric, which node is source and which node is drain? 2) Is the current source ideal, or a practical realization like a PMOS mirror?

Comment: (note that not all of these hints are specifically a statement that the common assumption is subverted for that question)

Comment: I had an interview recently and this circuit is based off of the question I was asked. The question was not this but I was wondering what would happen in the case I drew above. 
I can consider S/D to be interchangeable - in the end the device cares about two things - gate voltage should be higher than Vt w.r.t any one terminal and within the channel, the current flows from terminal of higher to terminal of lower voltage. I still don't understand how the current can be sunk in the given direction.

Comment: (1) If it's an ideal current source it's basically an unstoppable force and will destroy the transistor and arc through free space if it has to. But not only is this not an ideal current source, it isn't even the kind of current source that is a power source. It is the kind of current source that that throttles the current from another source (the 5V) so it is limited to a max of 5V. (2) Real MOSFETs have leakage. (3) This current source is very low to begin with potentially on par with leakage current of some MOSFETs. (4) Frankly Vs could be floating depending on how you look at it.

Comment: At your interview you should probably have asked if the current source was ideal or real.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of the question, "What happens where an un-stoppable force meets an immovable object?"

An *ideal* current source is like the unstoppable force.

An *ideal* FET is like  the immovable object.

In reality one has to give way:

1. The current source has a compliance voltage.
2. The FET has a breakdown voltage.

> What is the source voltage?

If the compliance voltage is reached before the breakdown voltage then the current source will transform into a voltage source. No charge will flow through the FET so the source voltage will be 0V.

If the breakdown voltage is reached before the compliance voltage then the FET will break over. Charge will flow (\$10\mu A\$ in this case) through the FET so the source voltage will be \$10^{-5}R_{1} \text{V}\$ in this case.

> How will the transistor turn on?

The transistor will not turn on! It will either be intact (off) or the drain-source will break over (punched through). It may or may not be destroyed depending on other real world limitations.

> To help sink the current, can the polarities at source or drain be such that the transistor is absorbing power instead of dissipating?

The transistor cannot absorb power ever. It can only dissipate.
When presenting these circuits, the components must be modeled appropriately.